# Shell - Skip matching lines while read

Tags: bash

I'm looking for help with my shell... Hope I'll find it here...

Here's my code :

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
  [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]*\# ]] && continue # This line must stay
  [[ "$line" =~ *read[[:space:]]-r[[:space:]]line* ]] && continue
  echo "${line%$NL}"
done < $0
```

First test will suppress "only comment lines".
Second test purpose is to suppress the "while IFS= read..." lines - **no matter what, it's just a test :-)**

"done < $0" has been here written intentionaly... for the test !

Running the shell outputs this :

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
    [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]*\# ]] && continue # This line must stay
    [[ "$line" =~ *read[[:space:]]-r[[:space:]]line* ]] && continue
    echo "${line%$NL}"
done < $0
```

as I thought the first line will be gone because of matching then 2nd test.

What's my mistake ?

***For the record, I don't want to use extra sed or awk sentence.***

Actually, the input data (here $0 file) has to be standard input (eg extract from tee command). I read lot of stackOverflow subject about this, with sed or awk responses that didn't match my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is invalid. A short test shows:

```
> [[ 'while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]' =~ *read[[:space:]]-r[[:space:]]line* ]]
> echo $?
2
```

The `*` can't be "alone"  - it can't be the first character in a [POSIX extended regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html). It has to "bind" to something, ex. a dot `.`. A dot represents any character. You want:

```
[[ $line =~ .*read[[:space:]]-r[[:space:]]line.* ]]
```

Comment: OK. Miss the "dots". I'll remember that one 8-)

Thanks !

Comment: Since regexes in Bash do substring matching, you can always drop `.*` at the start and end of a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is presence of starting quantifier `*` in the regex in second `continue` line. You may use:

```
[[ "$line" =~ read[[:space:]]+-r[[:space:]]+line ]] && continue
```

There is no need to match anything before `read` or after `line` in this regex.

Also it is better to use quantifier `+` after `[[:space:]]` to make it match 1 or more white spaces.

---

You can do more refactoring and combine both regex into one by using **alternation** as in this code:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
  [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*#|read[[:space:]]+-r[[:space:]]+line ]] && continue
  echo "${line%$NL}"
done < $0
```

Comment: Why does a starting `*` quantifier not result in an error message? After all, it doesn't have any term where it could be applied to.

Comment: @anubhava "You can do more refactoring and combine both regex into one by using alternation as in this code"
Response : I want to add more and more line pattern that each may be commented from time to time.

Comment: @BartmanDilaw: ok in that case you can keep separate conditions as I suggested in first part of answer. However I would still suggest to avoid using `.*` in regex as I suggested earlier for speedy regex evaluation.

Comment: @anubhava : OK. I didn't catch your first response... Thanks